# после того(,) как

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая?

Кукла начинает оживать после того(,) как примет более-менее человеческий облик.

Comment: Если вы хотите выразить кому-либо благодарность, напишите об этом в комментарии, или просто нажмите на стрелочку вверх напротив ответа. Наиболее полезный ответ можно отметить галочкой "лучший ответ", исправлять сам вопрос при этом не нужно, тем  более что-либо удалять, т. к. иначе ответы участников не смогут оценить другие пользователи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кукла начинает оживать после того, как примет более-менее человеческий облик.

Запятая нужна, в данном случае расчленяется составной союз ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК со значением времени. Расчленение союза подчеркивает значимость придаточного предложения, так как ударение в этом случае падает на местоименную часть союза.

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Vera, даже в этом случае такая пунктуация может быть только если автор подчеркивает значимость именно первой части.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь осложняется тем, что грамматика неоднозначна.
Является ли вторая часть подчиненным предложением - или самостоятельным неполным предложением с опущенным существительным.
Грамматика, насколько понимаю, вполне допускает второй вариант и тогда запятая ставится только перед "после" (если автор не настаивает на том, куда падает логическое ударение, но это здесь маловероятно)

В том случае, если составной союз целиком входит в придаточную часть, знаки препинания ставятся следующим образом:

> А) Если придаточная часть предложения следует за главной – запятая
>   ставится только перед союзом.
>
> [Калугин] рысцой ехал на бастион, с тем чтобы по приказанию генерала
>   передать туда некоторые приказания. Л. Толстой, Севастополь в мае. Мы
>   принялись бегать по закрайку самого берега, и все выходило отлично,
>   несмотря на то что кое-где лед ломался и выступала вода. Д.
>   Мамин-Сибиряк, Дурной товарищ.

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach3/

Таким образом, я полагаю, что вариант с запятой перед "после" (не не перед "как") как минимум не противоречит правилам.

*Кукла начинает оживать, после того как примет более-менее человеческий облик.*

А вот вариант

*Кукла начинает оживать после того, как примет более-менее человеческий облик. *

Возможен тогда и только тогда, когда автор настаивает на логическом ударении, падающем на первую часть. Ну например, в случае причинно-следственной связи, а не просто последовательности событий. Я бы контекст посмотрел, прежде чем определиться.

2 Vera
В дополонение к вышесказанному.
А если вы настаиваете, что здесь нет придаточного, то объясните почему.

Comment: текст:Фарфор вне изделия похож на младенца, которому, со временем, родитель-мастер подарит ему жизнь. Это может быть что угодно: чайный сервиз, просто изделия для дома или садовые безделушки, но фарфор начинает оживать после того, как примет более-менее человеческий облик.

Comment: куклой просто заменила т.к. мне нужно было

Comment: Да, здесь причинно-следственная связь. Тогда против запятой перед "как" (если автор того хочет) возражать не буду. Но тут другое. "человеческий облик" - очень уж разговорный оборот, едва ли не просторечный. В таком тексте выглядит несколько инородным.

Comment: Я не совсем поняла вашу мысль, поэтому еще раз коротко  определю грамматику предложения. Это СПП с придаточным времени и сложным союзом ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК. Расчленение союза меняет взаимное отношение главной и придаточной части.  При расчленении союза между частями существует взаимообусловленная связь, повышается значимость придаточного.  Если же союз не расчленять, то  главная часть является законченной по смыслу и форме и формально не зависит от придаточной, поэтому ее статус повышается. Этот вариант тоже возможен в качестве авторского выбора, учитывая, что семантика текста достаточно сложная.

Comment: Vera, это не лучший вариант со мной - повторять мысль. А что именно вы у меня не поняли?